# Python Tkinter - Error with widgets - TclError: expected integer but got "New"

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm following a basic Tkinter tutorial and I have followed it pretty much exactly but have used my minimal previous knowledge of Tkinter also. However, every time I have run it, I seem to be getting an error, but only with widgets.

The error message is:

`self.tk.call(_tkinter.TclError: expected integer but got "New"`

According to the error message, it is when I assign `Label(head)` to `lbl_logo on line 46`.

As I am doing this in college, I have to follow the tutorial which is why some of it could be reduced, ie: using .config

```
# Libraries
from tkinter import *



# generates password
class password_generator:


    def __init__(self):
        pass



# Window
class window():


    def __init__(self):

        # initial setup
        self.title('Safe G - The Password Generator')
        self.geometry('1600x900+100+100') # width (w), height (h), x-start-position (x), y-start-position (y)
        self.configure(bg='gray20')
        self.iconbitmap('safeg_icon.ico')

        # initial defaults
        self.option_add('*Font', 'Courier New')
        self.option_add('*Background', 'gray20')
        self.option_add('*Label.Font', 'Courier New')

        # constructs header
        head = Frame(self, highlightthickness=5, highlightbackground='tomato2')
        head.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        # HEADER - logo
        img = PhotoImage(file='file.gif') # isn't actually called file.gif, but is a .gif file
        lbl_logo = Label(head)
        lbl_logo.config(image = img)
        lbl_logo.image = img
        lbl_logo.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10, pady=10)

        # HEADER - title
        lbl_title = Label(head)
        lbl_title.config(text='Safe G - The Password Generator', font=('Courier New 20'))
        lbl_title.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10, pady=10)

        # constructs main body
        body = Frame(self, highlightthickness=5, highlightbackground='orange2')
        body.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        # constructs footer
        foot = Frame(self, highlightthickness=5, highlightbackground='gold')
        foot.pack(fill='both', expand=True)


# Initalises program
if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = Tk()
    window.__init__(win)
    win.mainloop()
```

It seems to work if I comment out any and all references to a label and the image seems to sometimes work if I do it outside the function.

Comment: The problem is obviously related to your use of 'Courier New' font, as that's the only place that 'New' appears in your code.  The issue is that you can't specify a font using a string if the name includes spaces: the 'New' is being parsed as the font size.  You need to write the font specifications as tuples: `("Courier New", 20)` for example, to bypass this parsing step.

Comment: Generally speaking, you shouldn't be calling the `window` class' `__init__()` method directly like that because that happens automatically when you create instances of the class by calling the class itself — i.e. `my_window = window()`. In addition, in that method something like `self.title('...')` isn't going to work because `self.title` doesn't exist at that point. That makes me think maybe `class window` is supposed to be a subclass of some other class, which is probably `Tk` — in which case the first thing it should do is call `Tk.__init__(self)` to initialize the base class.